# How to parse yaml file with string values

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

For the below example, I am trying to read this yaml file, parse it and write the contains under the `data` tag to a new yaml file. Using `yaml.load()` I am unable to differentiate between a string and int value.

Sample yaml file:

```
data:
    key1: "Value1"
    key2: Value2
```

My current parsing python code:

```
import io
import yaml

test_dict={}
with open("sample-string.yaml", "r") as stream:
    try:
        f = yaml.load(stream)
        test_dict['data'] = f['data']
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)

with io.open("output.yaml", "a",encoding="utf-8") as wf:
    try:
        yaml.dump(test_dict['data'],wf,allow_unicode=True,default_flow_style=False)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

The above file produces the below output:

```
key1: Value1
key2: Value2
```

As you can see the, the quotes are missing for the value of `key1` i.e. it should be `"Value1"` instead of `Value1`. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this ?

Expected output

```
key1: "Value1"
key2: Value2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the quote part of the data, or just its representation? If it's part of the data, you'll have to indicate that in the yaml.

```yaml
data:
    key1: |
        "Value1"
    key2: Value2
```

Note that enclosing quotes is optional on yaml string values, which means they must be explicitly included if they are to be part of the string data itself.

```yaml
# these two documents are identical
data:
- this
- that
- the other
---
data:
- "this"
- "that"
- "the other"
```

Comment: Its just a representation

Comment: @VasuMistry then I don't understand the question -- what you got is exactly what you want.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no way to write this in a yaml file? , `key1: "Value1"`

Comment: @VasuMistry see my edit: the enclosing quotes are optional. If the value is unambiguously a string it can be written without them.

Comment: `key1: 10` would be understood as an integer. If you wanted the string `"10"` you would HAVE to include the quotes, and python would properly parse it to be a string